# How to remove part of URL and exclude path from rewriting in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule !^/clients/index.php
RewriteRule ^clients/(.*) $1/$2
```

Idea is to rewrite all urls with clients in URL (eg. **mydomain.com/clients/cart.php** to **mydomain.com/cart.php**) but exclude this rule for **mydomain.com/clients/index.php**.

Using above rule, without my exclude rule works fine, but when I add `RewriteRule !^/clients/index.php`
rule gives me Internal Server Error.

Question is how to exclude full path from rewriting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
RewriteRule
!^/clients/index.php
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/clients/index.php
```

REWRITE :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/clients/index.php
RewriteRule ^clients/(.*) $1/ [NC,L]
```